# I don't understand why my data persists without volume binding

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  jenkins:

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
    networks:
      - jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
```

it couldn't be simpler

I launch the container, I create my account. Then I restart the container and I realize that my data persisted.

From what I know, there are only two ways to make the data persistent:

- run docker commit
- create a volume binding

I have not done either of these two operations, so why are my data not deleted?

If I do the same thing with another image (say gitea/gitea:latest), the data only persists if I do a volume biding.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the volume is persiste the data after the container remove. If you only restart the container, your data will be in the container.

Try stop, remove the container and run again. You will lose your data.

```
The data doesn’t persist when that container no longer exists, and it can be difficult to get the data out of the container if another process needs it.
```

[Storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)

Comment: Ok i run docker-compose down and my data was removed.
But why, when I stop gitea without volume binding, the data didn't persist ? I didn't removed the container, juste restarted it.

Comment: If you look `docker-compose down --help`: *Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images
created by `up`*